# New column with multiple conditions dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my sample data:

```
id <- c("1a","2c","3d","4f","5g","6e","7f","8q","9r","10v","11x","12l")
dg1 <- c(111234,902754,111235,111236,113456,123754,288563,396186,987654,987865,288563,396186)
dg2 <-c("",111235,111236,113456,"","","","","","",902754,902754)
df<-cbind(id,dg1,dg2)
```

I'd like to create a new column that indicates whether a string (111 or 113) is present across multiple columns such that my final df looks like this:

```
dt1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
df <- cbind(df,dt1)
```

I've tried to do this:

```
df %>%
  filter(any_vars(grepl('^(113|111)')))
```

and

```
df %>%
  select(contains("113","111"))
```

with the intention of tagging the filtered rows with mutate then doing a left join into the original data frame.

I've tried to Frankenstein together some code from similar problems to no avail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707016/add-new-column-if-range-of-columns-contains-string-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923392/select-columns-based-on-string-match-dplyrselect). I'm trying to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459752/can-dplyr-package-be-used-for-conditional-mutating) solution because my actual data has over a hundred columns to sort through with dozens of strings to search through (trying to avoid typing out and potentially missing a combination).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be:

Check whether either of `dg1` or `dg2` begin with 111 or 113 using `grepl()`

---

```
df <- df %>% mutate(dt1= ifelse(grepl("^111|^113", dg1) == TRUE |
                                grepl("^111|^113", dg2) == TRUE, 1, 0))
```

Output

```
> df
    id    dg1    dg2 dt1
1   1a 111234          1
2   2c 902754 111235   1
3   3d 111235 111236   1
4   4f 111236 113456   1
5   5g 113456          1
6   6e 123754          0
7   7f 288563          0
8   8q 396186          0
9   9r 987654          0
10 10v 987865          0
11 11x 288563 902754   0
12 12l 396186 902754   0
```

Test if equal to your desired output

```
dt1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
df1 <- cbind(df,dt1)

identical(df, df1)

> identical(df, df1)
[1] TRUE
```

---

As requested: to select multiple column names:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(dt1 = ifelse(any(grepl("^111|^113", across(dg1:dg99))),1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! Is there any way to do this if there's dg1-dg99 without typing out 100 lines of code?

Comment: It would be preferable if instead of using column names I could use column positions. For example: df %>% mutate(dt1= ifelse(grepl("^111|^113", [,c(2,3)] == TRUE, 1, 0))

Comment: @thou See the update

Comment: Thank you for the update! Any ideas why the multiple column names take a lot longer to process than your original answer? It's much faster to process: (grepl("^111|^113", dg1)==TRUE | .... copied and pasted a hundred times with changing "dg1" to desired variable rather than the across(dg1:dg99).

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but I know that some dplyr verbs (including `across`) had performance problems, at least in the past.

Comment: Just as a heads up, figured out that writing a function with: "ifelse(any(grepl("^111|^113", x)),1,0)}" that's used in "mutate(dt = apply(.[,2:3], MARGIN = 1, FUNCTION))" was much faster than using across in this instance. Copying and pasting dg1:dg99 a hundred times was the fastest.

Comment: Thanks for the remark! Will keep that in mind if I ever run into the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is.

**Data:**

```
id <- c("1a","2c","3d","4f","5g","6e","7f","8q","9r","10v","11x","12l")
dg1 <- c(111234,902754,111235,111236,113456,123754,288563,396186,987654,987865,288563,396186)
dg2 <-c("",111235,111236,113456,"","","","","","",902754,902754)
df<-cbind.data.frame(id,dg1,dg2)
```

**Code:**

```
    df = df %>% mutate(d1= str_match(df$dg1, '^(113|111)') %>% .[,1] %>% {ifelse(.> 0, 1,0 )}) %>% 
  mutate(d2 = str_match(df$dg2, '^(113|111)') %>% .[,1] %>% {ifelse(.> 0, 1,0 )})%>% 
  mutate(dt1 = ifelse(d1 > 0 | d2 > 0, 1,0)) %>% 
  select(id, dg1, dg2, dt1)

    id    dg1    dg2 dt1
1   1a 111234          1
2   2c 902754 111235   1
3   3d 111235 111236   1
4   4f 111236 113456   1
5   5g 113456          1
6   6e 123754         NA
7   7f 288563         NA
8   8q 396186         NA
9   9r 987654         NA
10 10v 987865         NA
11 11x 288563 902754  NA
12 12l 396186 902754  NA
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the quick reply. Is there a way to go through dg1-99 without typing out each line of code?